# Get the total counts after faceting in solr4.0

Tags: solr, facet

I am using `solr 4.0` and have the following query :

`http://localhost:8987/solr/select/?q=priority%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=0&indent=on&facet=on&facet.field=priority&facet.mincount=1`

This returns the following :

`<lst name="priority">
<int name="67JP 0041952">1</int>
<int name="67SU 1140793">1</int>
<int name="69SU 1328511">1</int>
<int name="AU 2007 242957">2</int>
<int name="AU 2008 201480">1</int>
<int name="CN 1993 103001">3</int>
<int name="CN 1997 106616">1</int>
</lst>`

The field `priority` is multivalued. Now what i want to achieve is to get the total counts from the result returned after faceting i.e. 10. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the total count of the facets you need to check [SOLR-2242](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2242)
The fix version is Solr 4.0, so this should be available in the Current build.

Comment: I have checked this before but in solr 4.0 this is not working and i am not able to find the alternative for this in the current version.

Comment: yup its seems the patch is not applied in the 4.0 Alpha version. You would need to apply the patch provided in the link. The param is numTerms by which you the distinct count.

Comment: Can you please tell how to apply the patch in solr 4.0. I have downloaded the file solr-2242 from the link

Comment: You can download the source and if you have svn client on windows can simply right click and use apply patch to apply it. Also check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToContribute#Working_With_Patches

Comment: Thanks. I am working on ubuntu system and i guess i will need to do it from the terminal from the second link. Please correct me if i miss something.